# jFugue Saving MIDI Files While Still Including Loaded Instruments

Tags: jfugue

I am using an external soundfont to play MusicStrings and everything is working find. When I use player.saveMidi(etc, etc) the files are saved with the original MIDI soundfont.

```
Soundbank soundbank = MidiSystem.getSoundbank(new File("SGM-V2.01.sf2"));
Synthesizer synth = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
synth.open();
synth.loadAllInstruments(soundbank);
Player player = new Player(synth);
Pattern pattern = new Pattern("C5majw C5majw C5majw");
player.play(pattern); // works fine with external soundbank
player.saveMidi(pattern, filename); //Doesn't save with external soundbank instruments
```

Is there any workaround or built in feature that supports this functionality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that MIDI is a set of musical instructions. Regardless of whether you load a soundbank into the Java program, when you save as MIDI, you're only saving musical instructions. (By "musical instructions", I mean things like "NOTE ON" or "INSTRUMENT CHANGE" but not actual musical sound data)

It sounds like what you want to do is render your music into a WAV file using the sounds from the soundbank that you have loaded. To do this, you'll want to use the Midi2WavRenderer available here: http://www.jfugue.org/code/Midi2WavRenderer.java

Comment: Another solution is to change the soundbank used by the midi-player application.  This may require selecting an appropriate, configurable, midi-player.